# “Кисть" и "кидать”, “пасть" и "падать” — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Могут ли быть слова “кисть - кидать” и “пасть - падать” однокоренными?

По аналогии с:

весть ведать;
страсть страдать;
власть обладать;
сласть сладость;
прясть прядь;
красть обкрадывать;
зависть завидывать;
класть клад;
вывести вывод;
соблюсти соблюдать;
ясти ядь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кисть-кидать никак не родственны, согласна с Aer♦, а вот пасть и падать всё-таки этимологические родственники, судя по этимол. словарям:

Фасмер о происхождении слова пасть:

> Пасть - про́пасть, чеш. раst᾽ ж. «ловушка». Первично, по-видимому,
>   знач. «пропасть», от паду́. Ср. знач. в.-луж. khlama «морда, пасть» из
>   нем. Klamme «овраг» (Штрекель, AfslPh 14, 527) см. паду́.

У Шанского:

> Пасть (зев). Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -tь) от *padti (>
>   пасть). Первоначально — «впадина» (такое значение в диалектах еще
>   отмечается). См. падать. Пасть (глагол). Общеслав., имеющее
>   соответствия в др. индоевроп. языках. Соврем. пасть из *padti после
>   изменения dt > ст и отпадения конечного безударного и. Ср. падать.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

А вот у Г.Цыганенко:

> ПАДАТЬ - <лететь сверху вниз>, <валиться на землю>, <идти, выпадать>
>   (об атмосферных осадках). Древн. слав. слово. Праслав. *padati
>   <падать>, форма повторяющегося действия, как и соответствующая ей
>   форма некратного действия *padti, давшая после изменения dt > tt > cm
>   и падения конечного безударного -и соврем, форму пасть2, происходит от
>   и.-е. *podti <пасть>, собств. <свалиться вниз>. От падти с пом. суф.
>   -еж-ь образовано сущ. падежь > падёж (скота); с суф. -енщ-е - сущ. падение <отвлеч. действие пасть> (ср. от падать - падание). В глаг.
>   *padti и.-е. корень*pod-/*ped- <низ> (изменение б > а). От и.-е. *pod- с кратк. гласи. 6 (6 > о) в рус. яз. сущ. под1 <низ> (печи) и вторичн.
>   под2 - предл. См. падеж. пасть'1, педаль, пехота, подошва, почва.

http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC

> ПАСТЬ 1 - <зев, рот зверя, рыбы>. В рус. словарях фиксируется с I пол.
>   XVIII в. Образовано с пом. предметного суф. -ть (как горсть} от корня
>   пад- <низ, дол> - того же, что в глаг. *падти (см. падать).
>   Предполагаемое *падть претерпело изменение дт > mm > cm. Слово пасть!
>   < *падть первонач. значило <впадина>, <провал>, <пропасть> (см.
>   Словарь Даля), а затем - <глубина рта, зев живота.>. От пасть1
>   <провал> с прист. про-(по типу приставочных глаг.) - сущ. пропасть
>   <очень глубокая расщелина>, <беспредельная глубина>. См. пасть2
>
> ПАСТЬ 2 - паду <погибнуть на поле боя> (книжн.). Общеслав. Имеет
>   соответствия D других и.-е. языках. Соврем, слово развилось из
>   др.-рус. пасти <упасть, умереть> вследствие утраты конечного
>   безударного -и (ср. укр. вмети <упасть>, где -и сохраняется). Др.-рус.
>   пасти восходит к праслав. *padti <пасть>. В нем **dt > tt > st**.
>   Праслав. *padti представляет собой застывший дат. п. сущ. *padtb <низ,
>   провал, впадина>. Следоват., пасть 2 буквально значит <падать вниз,
>   проваливаться> > <падать на землю>, <валиться на землю> > <погибнуть>.
>   От *padti > пасть2 с прист. pro- > про- образован глаг. *propadti >
>   пропасть <потеряться>, <исчезнуть>, а от него с суф. -а- - глаг.
>   несоверш. вида пропадать.

http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%AC

В связи с этим  ещё интересный факт в словаре Г.Цыганенко:

> ГОРСТЬ - <ладонь и пальцы руки, сложенные так, чтобы зачерпнуть,
>   захватить что-либо>. По корню праслав, Развилось из *gorttb
>   <горсть> вследствие расподобления (диссимиляции) tt > st. **Сущ. *gorttb
>   образовано с пом. суф. -t-ь (как пасть) от *gort- с и.-е. корнем
>   *gor-/*ger- <собирать>. Ср. с этим корнем глаг. gortati > рус. диал. гортать <сгребать>, укр. пригортати <пригребать>, <прижимать>, горнути
>   <грести>, <обнимать>. Горсть - <то, чем пригребают, хватают что-либо>,**
>   <ладонь и пальцы руки> (ср. укр. урменя, от жму), далее - <то, что
>   можно захватить ладонью с пальцами>, напр., горсть зерна и т. п. Ср.
>   лтш. gurste <связка льна>;укр. горстка <пучок?, <небольшой сноп>. См.
>   грабить, грести.

http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Так что кисть не то, чем кидают, а вот горсть - то, чем "гортают".

Answer (score 1):

А почему вы считаете возможным возведение *кисти* к *кидать*? Семантически эти слова едва ли связаны. (То, чем кидают, не подходит. Кистью никто ничего не кидает.) А вот, напр., др.-рус. слово *кита* «связка, пучок травы» выглядит более правдоподобным источником. Кисть (руки) действительно похожа на пучок (пальцев).

Есть версия, что слово *пасть* (животного) действительно связано с глаголом *падать* (якобы *пасть* изначально — «впадина, пропасть»), однако семантически это не слишком убедительно.

Comment: Кистью нельзя кинуть камень?

Comment: @prostorech обычно говорят рукой, и кидают рукой. Кистью ничего не делают (ну, на ум точно ничего не приходит).

Comment: А кисть сама разве не раскинута как листья пальмы? (то, что раскинуто "раскинутая")

Comment: @prostorech боюсь, что нет, но тут уже возникают фонетические проблемы. Нужно объяснять связь *раскинуть* и *кисть*.

Answer (score 0):

Слова "кисть" и слово "кидать" не однокоренные.Слова "пасть" (если не имеется ввиду ""челюсти", "рот" и т.п.) и  "падать" - однокоренные.