# Весна и водная — однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология

Относятся ли существительное *весна* и краткое прилагательное *водна* к этимологически однокоренным, учитывая наличие в русском языке чередования гласных е->о и согласных [с->д](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5):

в**ес**ти в**од**ить;
бр**ес**ти бр**од**ить;
ш**ес**твие х**од**ить.

Примечание: одним из переводов английского слова *spring* на русский язык, помимо общелексического *весна*, является также слово *родник (источник)*.

Answer (score 1):

Ни в одном этимологическом словаре не нашёл предположений об их родственности. Слово *весна* связывают со словом *весёлый*, например у Цыганенко:

> > **ВЕСЁЛЫЙ** «находящийся в радостном состоянии, жизнерадостный». Праславянское. Первичное знач, полагают, было «светлый, радостный». Это слово образовано с суф. -ел-, как *тяжелый*, от той же и.-е. основы *ves-, что и в слове *весна*.
> >
> > **ВЕСНА** «время года: март, апрель, май». Праславянское. Образовано,  вероятно, с суф. -н-а со значениеи состояния (как *тайна*) от и.-е. корня *ves- со значением «светить». Ср. др.-инд. *vesantas* «весна», *vasaras* «день».