# Пестун и педагог — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Относятся ли слова пестун и педагог к однокоренным, учитывая наличие в русском языке чередования согласных [с->д](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5):

шествие / ход;

вести / водить;

брести / бродить.

Comment: Абсолютно не против Ваших вопросов, они интересны. Но можно спросить из любопытства: Вы пишете курсовую по этимологии? Есть ли от нас какая-то помощь? Почему не приняли ни один ответ?

Comment: курсовую не пишу) вопросы, в основном, накапливались по прочтении старославянской библии

Comment: Интересно... И только сейчас они все потекли потоком?

Comment: что-то фиксировал, что-то держалось в голове

Comment: @prostorech похвальное любопытство к языку! А как же вы читаете по-старославянски? Вы учили язык? Или со словарем и помощью русского?

Comment: @Aer читал про образование аориста, остальное при многократном повторении в тексте и наличии сопровождающего его контекста ложится само собой + https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/eng/

Comment: построчные переводы на других языках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Больше похоже на этимологические синонимы.

В словаре Шанского:

> Песту́н (воспитатель). Общеслав. Суф. производное от утраченного pěstъ
>   «пища», суф. образования (суф. -тъ) от той же основы (с
>   перегласовкой), что питать (см.). Исходное *pěttъ > pěstъ в результате
>   расподобления взрывных tt > ст (как вести).

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD

ПЕДАГОГ в словаре Успенского:

> Греческое «пайдагогос» сложено из «пайс» — «дитя», «мальчик» и
>   «агогос» — «ведущий». Буквально — «детруковод», «детовод».

Оба воспитатели ребёнка. Сейчас семантика разная (пестун - нянька, даёт пищу в прямом смысле, педагог - в переносном, даёт пищу для ума), но этимологически восходят к одному значению - "слуга при ребёнке".

Comment: «Этимологически восходят к одному значению» звучит как-то странно ) Может, «исторически» будет лучше?

Comment: Почему странно? Происходят от слов с похожим смыслом - "слуга", история слова и происхождение слова в данном смысле близки, но ведь мы имеем в виду источник, а не то, как слова изменялись.

Answer (score 2):

Нет.

Во-первых, "чередования" такого нет это явление другого порядка. Вернее сказать - разные явления, ваши примеры нельзя вообще причесать под одну гребенку. Не буду сейчас углубляться, это отдельная тема.

А во-вторых и в-главных, пестовать и педагог - это случайное созвучие, не более. Пестовать - исконно славянское слово, педагог - заимствование довольно позднее. 
Ни по каким критерием слова не могут считаться однокоренными.

Другое дело, что на очень древнем, праиндоевропейском уровне возможна какая-то родственность, но это все умозрительные гипотезы. Проблема в том, что этимология "пестовать" довольно туманна, но в целом оно восходит к морфу со значением "толочь" (в ступе).

У Фасмера:

> I, род. п. -а́, пе́стик, словен. pẹ́sta, чеш. píst м., písta ж. –
>   то же, слвц. piest, польск. рiаstа, в.-луж., н.-луж. pěsta, сюда же
>   чеш. рěсhоvаti "утрамбовывать, утаптывать; набивать".
>
> Праслав. *pěstъ родственно лит. piestà "ступа", вин. piẽstą,
>   piẽstas "пест", лтш. pìesta – то же (Скарджюс, Žod. Dar. 18), далее
>   связано с пиха́ть, пшено́, а также с лит. paisýti "очищать от мякины
>   зерна ячменя", др.-инд. pináṣṭi "толчет, растирает", piṣṭás
>   "молотый", лат. pinso, -еrе, pistum "толочь"; см. Траутман, ВSW 221;
>   Вальде–Гофм. 2, 307 и сл.; Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 166; Маценауэр, LF 15,
>   168.

А вот педагог - вообще от греческого piados - ребенок. Вряд ли тут что-то общее...

Comment: Пестун вроде тоже с ребёнком связан https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/79025

Comment: @prostorech это не этимологическая связь. А медвежонок - вообще седьмая вода на киселе в этом родстве. Пестуном называли дядьку при княжеских отроках, тогдашний аналог гувернера. На медвежонка перенесли позже - по аналогии. Так вот тот, исходный, дядька-пестун через значение пестовать (заботиться) однозначно связать с пестить - (толочь). Именно так воспринимался процесс воспитания - перемалыванием всего для получения отборного продукта-результата.

Answer (score 0):

Никак нет, они из разных языков.

[ПЕСТУН](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD)

> Из праслав., от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав.
>   пѣстунъ (παιδαγωγός; Остром.), русск. пестун, пе́стовать «нянчить»,
>   арханг. (Подв.), вятск. (Васн.), укр. пiсту́н, пiстова́ти, белор.
>   песту́н, пестова́ць, словенск. pẹstȗn «воспитатель», pẹ́stovati, -ujem
>   «носить на руках, манить (ребенка)», чешск. pěstoun, словацк. pestún,
>   польск. piastun — то же, piastować «воспитывать, нянчить».

[ПЕДАГОГ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3)

> Происходит от др.-греч. παιδαγωγός «воспитатель, наставник; букв.
>   (раб) ведущий мальчиков», из др.-греч. παῖς (παιδίον) «дитя, мальчик»
>   (откуда παιδεία «воспитание, обучение») + ἀγωγός «ведущий, тот, кто
>   ведёт», далее из ἄγω «вести; гнать, управлять», далее из праиндоевр.
>   *ag'- «гнать». В большинстве европейских языков слово заимств. через лат. paedagogus.