# Шестун, ходули, шест

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова шестун, ходули и шест  к этимологически однокоренным, учитывая наличие в русском языке чередования гласных о->е и согласных [д->с](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5), х->ш:

в**од**ить в**ес**ти;
бр**од**ить бр**ес**ти ;
х**од** ш**ес**твие .

умор умер**т**вие ;
ход шес**т**вие;
ядь яс**т**вие

То есть:

две ходули -> один шест

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448198/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5

Comment: Количество «чередующихся» букв превышает имеющееся. Не смущает?

Comment: Примечание, не относящееся ко всему тексту, надо оформлять сноской.

Comment: @shampar а Вас связка ход -> шествие не смущает?

Comment: @shampar умор ->умертвие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нельзя.** Вот что пишет об этимологизации слова *шест* А. А. Кретов:

> Ясно, что семантика должна восходить к 'сечь', но примирить эту семантику и форму слова можно, лишь предположив балтийское заимствование.

А. К. Шапошников пишет:

> Наконец, возможно толкование на основе праслав. *шьд-, соотносительного с перегласовкой с *ход-, т.е. *шьстъ из *шьд-тъ.

Но такая версия вызывает вопросы: почему, если это слово образовано от общеславянской основы, оно отсутствует в других славянских языках? И, более того, разве шест ходит? На шесте ходят? Шест используют как трость? Как объяснить семантическое развитие?

Ходули связаны  с *шёл* 'пр. вр. от *идти*' и *ходить*, что очевидно (о чередовании шед-//ход- см. выше).

Answer (score 2):

Есть гипотеза, что *шест* восходит к той же основе, что и *ход*, но Преображенский, Фасмер, Черных считают её малоубедительной и возводят *шест* к корню *ks- «скрести», и, таким образом, родственниками ему приходятся слова *чесать* и *шесть*. Приведу цитату из словаря Черных:
[image: Выдержка из словаря Черных.]

Answer (score 2):

```
 Можно ли отнести слова шестун, ходули и шест к этимологически 
 однокоренным
```

Ни разу не слышала слово "шестун", вот "шастун" (как шатун) у Даля есть - от шастать.

По Шанскому:

> (болтаться, шататься). Искон. Возникло на базе шастать — «бросать
>   зерно в одну и другую сторону в решете при его просеивании», суф.
>   производного от звукоподражательного шаст.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Фамилия Шестун происходит от числительного шесть - шестой ребёнок.

Ходули - от "ходить", корень -ход-

Шест восходит к праславянскому *sьstъ - палка. Даже индоевропейские корни разные: шест -*kes/*kos ; ход - *sed/*sod.

Видимо, Вас сбило слово шествие. Мои ученики тоже проводили параллели: шествовать - идти прямо, как шест. Нет, друзья, шествовать - идти медленно и важно, шест здесь ни при чём. Шествие этимологически связано с корнем шед- (шьд-). Это заимствование из старославянского языка , вторичная форма из шьстие (движение, хождение), вставной звук в появился под влиянием слов на - ствие (действие) Шьстие образовано с помощью суф. -tij-e (из причастного суф. -т- и именного -иj-е)
-шьд-т-иj-е. Оказавшиеся рядом звуки дт изменились в тт, потом в ст (как известие).

Вот ход- в "ходить" и шед- в формах глагола идти — исконно морфы одного и того же корня: шед- возникло из *хьд-. http://russkiyyazik.ru/905/

Но и формы с этими корнями нельзя назвать однокоренными. Это явление 
 называется супплетивизмом (идти, идут, идущий - шёл, шла, шедший). Супплетивизм (от позднелат. suppletivus -дополняющий) - образование форм одного и того же слова от разных корней. Корневые морфы таких словоформ лишены формальной (фонематической) близости и потому не могут объединяться в одну морфему.

Так что это совершенно разные слова, не однокоренные.