# Подагра, пождь — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "подагра" и "пождь" к этимологически однокоренным, по аналогии с [педагог -> пестун](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448198/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего можно, так как 'пождь'  означает низ, дно, схоже со словом 'под', а оно в свою очередь родственно со словом 'подагра', ведь при подагре обычно,  больной испытывает боль в ногах, то есть внизу, 'под' телом. Вот о подагре:

Происходит от др.-греч. ποδάγρα «подагра» (буквально «ловушка для ног»), из πούς (род. п. ποδός) «нога», далее из праиндоевр. *ped- «нога» + ἄγρα «ловля, охота». Русск. подагра — книжное заимств. через польск. роdаgrа из лат. роdаgrа.

Слово "под", возможно,  и произошло от слова *ped-"нога" из праиндоевропейского, так как нога находится "под" телом. Так что "пождь" могло использоваться в смысле "под", то есть "пождь" - > "под"  - > "подагра".