# Быть и будущее — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, историческая-фонетика

Можно ли отнести слова быть и будущее к этимологически однокоренным исходя из следующего:

1. Выпадение согласной корня "д" перед глагольным окончанием -ть

Например, да**д**им, но да**ть**

2. Наличие в русском чередования согласных с/д (см. [я**д**ь -> я**с**ти](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5));
3. Наличие в русском чередования у/ы (ст**у**д -> ст**ы**дение, возд**у**х -> возд**ы**хание, сл**у**х -> сл**ы**шание)

То есть:

1. бы**ть** -> бу**д**ущее;
2. бы**с**ть* -> бу**д**ущее;
3. б**ы**ть -> б**у**дущее

*вылезающее при спряжении

Answer (score 2):

*Быть* и *будущее*, конечно, однокоренные, но вопрос о том, как образовалась форма *бу**д**у* при *бы( ̶д̶)ть*, открыт. Тут не объяснено не столько чередование ы//у, сколько внезапно появляющийся звук *д*.

Вот что приводит А. Камчатнов на своем [сайте](http://www.drevoslov.ru/bytitree/1697-budu):

> *Буд/у, -ешь* гл., буд. вр. к *быть*. Ст.-сл. бѫдѫ. «Особое положение данной формы в глагольной парадигме (своеобразный перфективный презенс в роли будущего времени), а главное — недостаточная этимологич. выясненность **bǫdǫ* побуждает нас трактовать эту форму как самостоятельную лексическую единицу, позднее супплетивно грамматикализованную как будущее время от гл. **byti* (см.). Как бы то ни было, не оставляет сомнений близкое родство с **byti*, точнее — происхождение из одного из дослав. вариантов соответствующего и.-е. корня» (ЭССЯ 2, 233-234).