# Частица «еда» и глагол «быти»

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести вопросительную частицу "еда" и глагол "быти" к этимологически однокоренным исходя из нижеследующего:

1. Наличие словоформ есмь, еси, есть  и т.д. у глагола в настоящем времени
2. Наличие в русском чередования согласных с/д (см. [я**д**ь -> я**с**ти](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5));
3. Образование вопросительного предложения по "европейскому" типу (перемещение вспомогательного глагола в начало предложения)
   **Est**-ce seulement par Moïse que l'Éternel **parle**?
   **Еда** ли моисию единому **глагола** господь?
4. Присутствие аналогии склонения с глаголом ясти:

Сущ. я**д**ь; гл. ясти

Спряжение:

я ямъ
ты я**си**
мы ямы
вы я**сте**
он я**сть**

Сущ. е**д**а?; гл. быти

Спряжение:

я есмь
ты е**си**
мы есмы
вы е**сте**
он е**сть**

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, нет ли у вас возможности писать по-английски? ваш вопрос похож на те, которые задаются на сайте Linguistics.

Comment: задал по-аглицки

Answer (score 2):

**Нельзя.** Ответ очень прост: если словоформы включаются в одну парадигму, это не значит, что они однокоренные.

Так, глагол *быть* в форме наст. вр. 3 л. ед. ч. выглядит как *есть*. Нетрудно заметить, что *быть* не выводимо из *есть* (и наоборот), *есть* — супплетивная словоформа, содержащая иной корень, чем в *быть*.

Другой вопрос, однокоренные ли *еда* 'частица' и *есть* 'pres. к *быть*'. Ответ — **нет**. В *еда*, видимо, содержится частица **ed-* (та же, что, например, в ***ед**иный*). (См. ЭСРЯ.)