# Еда ли, есть ли, если

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести вопросительную частицу "еда" и союз "если" к этимологически однокоренным исходя из нижеследующего:

1. Наличие в старославянском чередования согласных д/с (см. [ядь -> ясти](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448136/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5));
2. Наличие переходной формы еда ли -> естъли -> если
3. Наличие у некоторых глаголов, стоящих в 3-м лице ед.ч. аориста двух взаимозаменяемых форм:
   [**бы( ̶д̶)**/**быс**ть;](https://azbyka.ru/cerkovnoslavyanskij-yazyk-v-tablicax#n10)
   **пи**/**пи**тъ;
   на**чя**/на**чя**тъ;
   **жи**/**жи**тъ;
   **яд**е/**яс**ть;
   **дад**е/**дас**ть

То есть:

**ед**а **ес**тъ

Comment: Еда ли - это едва ли? Или именно еда?

Comment: @Людмила еда. Например: Книга пророка Михея 3:11

и къ господеви не почиваху глаголюще, еда ли господь в насъ, не приидетъ зло на ны

Comment: http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/soyuzyi-soyuznyie-sochetaniya-122884.html - Может быть, Вам будет интересно. Времени сейчас нет копаться в архаике, но однокоренными еда и если  никак не назовёшь, родственными - да в каком-то смысле. В этой фразе значение "нежели" ( ЕДА - разве, неужели, ли, или, нежели). Вот частица ли - одна и та же в "еда ли", "есть ли = естьли = если". А еда скорее ближе по корню к "егда = е+гда, ко+гда=кода(диал.)"